# Regression Estimates equal 0, is there something wrong with the model?

Tags: r, regression, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression, offset

[image]

```
m1<- glm.nb(number ~ Force+SelfEthnicity+offset(log(`Resident Population`)), data=df_merge2)

> dput(head(df_merge, 20))
structure(list(Force = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("BTP", 
"Cumbria", "South-Wales"), class = "factor"), SelfEthnicity = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Asian", "Black", "Other", "White"), class = "factor"), 
    month = structure(c(17440, 17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17622, 
    17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 
    17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048), class = "Date"), number = c(2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    16L, 5L, 3L, 3L), roll_sum = c(2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 
    13L, 15L, 16L, 21L, 23L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 34L, 37L, 51L, 55L, 
    56L, 57L), `Resident Population` = c(4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 
    4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 
    4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 4213531, 
    4213531, 4213531, 4213531), rate = c(0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 
    0.002, 0.003, 0.003, 0.004, 0.004, 0.005, 0.005, 0.007, 0.007, 
    0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.012, 0.013, 0.013, 0.014)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    Force = structure(1L, levels = c("BTP", "Cumbria", "South-Wales"
    ), class = "factor"), SelfEthnicity = structure(1L, levels = c("Asian", 
    "Black", "Other", "White"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:20), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
>
```

For this model I got the estimates above however when I exponentiate them, the Force estimates go to 0.
Does this mean my model is bad or how should I interpret this?

Comment: Why do you force the model to have no intercept? Also, please provide information about the data, the variables and the goal of the analysis. And avoid adding code or alphanumeric output as images for these [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9566484). You can copy-paste the output of the model summary directly.

Comment: I have put in the intercept and added a summary, how would I interpret these estimates? @dipetkov

Comment: Thank you for the updates. You've already received a helpful answer about interpreting the coefficients, I have nothing to add to it.

Comment: However, before interpreting anything, I would step back and ask myself whether fitting this model to this data makes sense. In the attached data the same combination of `(Force, SelfEthnicity, Resident Population)` is repeated over a monthly series of `number`s from 2017-10-01 to 2019-06-01. The time dimension is ignored altogether in the current model.

Comment: I suggest to consider writing a new question which describes the data, the variables and the question you want to answer with the data. You can also include the model you've proposed here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this count data model,

$$\mathtt{E}[y \vert x,d,p]=\exp\{\alpha + \beta \cdot x+\gamma \cdot d +\log{p}\}$$

The change in expected $y$ associated with going from $d=0$ to  $d=1$ is

$$\mathtt{E}[y \vert x,d=1,p]-\mathtt{E}[y \vert x,d=0,p]=\exp\{\beta \cdot x+\gamma \cdot 1 +\log{p}\} - \exp\{\beta \cdot x  +\log{[p}\}$$

That could be quite large even if $\gamma$ is quite small. For example, $$\exp\{10 - 13\} - \exp\{10\}=-22,026.416.$$

This is a large *additive* effect.

You can also think of $\exp{\gamma}$ as a *multiplicative* effect since $$\mathtt{E}[y \vert x,d=1,p]=\exp\{\beta \cdot x+\gamma \cdot 1 +\log{p}\}=\mathtt{E}[y \vert x,d=0,p] \cdot \exp{\gamma}$$

Since $\exp\{-13\}=0.00000226$, that's quite a bit of shrinkage from $d$. Nothing to sneeze at if you're multiplying rather than adding.

In my example above, you are taking $\exp\{10\}=22,026.466$ to $$\exp\{10\} \cdot \exp\{-13\} = 0.04978707.$$

I would also recommend that you consider adding the constant back in. By dropping it, you are forcing the coefficients on the omitted categories for your dummies to zero. This usually makes no sense as a constraint.

Comment: I have added back the intercept but am still confused as to how to estimate the coefficients @dimitriy

Comment: @Emily Can you clarify what is confusing you in my answer? The code you posted is not reproducible, so it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Taking the estimate ForceCumbria exp(4.16885)=64.64. How would I roughly interpret this in terms of the Neg Binom glm? @dimitriy

Comment: It's a 65X increase in the expected number. The expected count for a White BTP unit with a population of 4213531 is exp(-13.28788 + log(4213531)) = 7.141562. The expected count for White Cumbria unit with a population of 4213531 is exp(-13.28788 + 4.16885 + log(4213531)) = 461.6382, and  461.6382/7.141562 = 64.64107.

Comment: @Emily Did that clear things up?

Comment: I thinks so, yes thank you @dimitriy

Comment: @Emily If so, you can pick it as the answer by clicking on the check mark.